# Navigating to default route ('') causes page to scroll

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using `route.navigate()` to trigger routes in my application, with pushState disabled. When triggering the default route (`router.navigate('', { trigger: true })`, the page scrolls to the top, as if a regular `#` link had been followed.

You can see this in action here:

https://jsfiddle.net/k58tstas/

From reading the Backbone source, it uses `window.location.hash` to update the URL, and when that is set to `''` it translates to `'#'` and causes a scroll jump to that root anchor.

A quick, dirty solution is to have a named route for the default and use that, but is there a nicer way to disable this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

If you start the router with the `pushState` option

```
Backbone.history.start( { pushState: true } );
```

the issue will go away (except in some older browsers). I realize you have made a conscious decision to leave it off, but unfortunately, from what I've been able to gather, turning it on is the only way to suppress that behaviour.

Comment: This does solve the problem, for pushState supporting browsers. Which should be all the ones we care about, but unfortunately not on this particular project!

Answer (score -1):

Try placing the Backbone.history.start(); before instantiating the router object.

```
$(function() {
   Backbone.history.start();
    window.router = new Router();

    $('.js-root').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        window.router.navigate('', { trigger: true });
    });

    $('.js-queenslanders').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        window.router.navigate('queenslanders', { trigger: true });
    });       
});
```

Comment: Sorry @pushkar, this doesn't make any difference.